# Unable to send file more than 5MB via wordpress form using office365 smtp

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, apache2.2, memory-limit

I am facing the issue of sending file more than 5MB from wordpress form to office365 email via office365 smtp on live server. I can't send 5MB . But I can send less than 5MB.  When I check the php.ini file, Here is the setting:  memory_limit = 128M / post_max_size = 512M /upload_max_filesize = 512M.  Also I setup 20MB on wordpress form. Could you please advice me how to set up more? Thank you.

I have tried to test the website on localhost using office365 smtp. It works and I can send 15 MB file via wordpress form. I am using apache server 2.2 for live and  pache server 2.4 on localhost.